# Mixture of Experts of ANN and KNN

Tags: image, machine-learning, neural-network

i'm looking for a new approch that hels me to mixture artificial neural network and k-nearest neighbor to improve their efficacity

Comment: So what exactly do you want to know? :)

Comment: Obviously you have something mind to suggest these two techniques, so maybe give a little more detail.  However, I'd suggest forgetting about these techniques and trying to understand your data or problem well before you choose a technique.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [ensemble methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). Two of the most common techniques are bagging and boosting. They usually combine multiple models of the same type. But it should not be a problem to combine different types of classifiers.